# UITextField underline width issue

Tags: swift, uiview, uitextfield, viewdidappear

I have a `UITextField` & `UIButton` placed inside a vertical `UIStackView`. Programatically, I've added a `UIView` to serve as an underline of the `UITextField`.

The problem comes when I compile the code. The line is longer than the text field. I've printed the width of all of the objects above and it says `335`.

I call this `function` in `viewWillAppear` and the line is longer. If I call it in `viewDidAppear`, the line is the exact width of the `UITextField` but you can see the button and text field flash very briefly before updating the view. What am I doing wrong?
[image]
[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad()  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    observeKeyboardNotifications()
    textFieldDelegate()
    setupRegisterButton()

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     setupTextFields()
}

func setupTextFields() {

    emailTextField.leftViewMode = .always
    let emailIconView = UIImageView()
    emailIconView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 23, height: 17)
    emailIconView.image = UIImage(named: "icon_email")
    let bgIconView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 28, height: 17))
    bgIconView.addSubview(emailIconView)
    emailTextField.leftView = bgIconView

    emailTextField.tintColor = .white
    emailTextField.textColor = .white
    emailTextField.backgroundColor = .red
    emailTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    let bottomLineEmail = CALayer()
    bottomLineEmail.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 29, width: emailTextField.frame.width, height: 1)
    print("Email width", emailTextField.frame.width)
    print("button width", retrievePasswordButton.frame.width)
    print("line width", bottomLineEmail.frame.width)
    bottomLineEmail.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    emailTextField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLineEmail)
    //emailTextField.backgroundColor = .clear
    emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string     : emailTextField.placeholder!,
                                                              attributes : [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: Colors.authTextFieldPlaceholderColor])
    retrievePasswordButton.isEnabled = false
    handleTextFields()
}
```

Comment: Don't add views/layers in `viewWillAppear`, the method can be called multiple times. No, the frames won't be correct in `viewWillAppear`. Use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Also this would be much simpler with a simpler `UIView` and autolayout.

Comment: @Sulthan calling it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` didnt work as expected though. The width of the underline is still longer than the text field itself.

Comment: @Dani instead of adding layer why don't you add a view of that size and constraint inside of your stack view.

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger yes, that's what I've ended up doing. Seems to be a lot easier. Thank you

Comment: @Dani Great to hear that. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it personally
it works in ViewWillLayoutSubviews

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews();
    self.setupTextFields()
}
```

and viewDidAppear

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.setupTextFields();
}
```

[image: proof]